# angular 2 firebase dropdown selector

Tags: angular, firebase

I am learning Angular 4 and firebase. Here, i'm trying to build a dropdown selector for a list of courses.

After selecting a course, the course description should appear in another div below.

courses.component.html

```html
<select class="form-control" 
     [ngModel]="(selectedCourse$ | async)" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
>
<option *ngFor="let course of (courses$ | async)" 
     [ngValue]="course"
>
    {{ course.description }}
</option>
</select>
      
<div *ngIf="(selectedCourse$ | async)">
   {{ course.description }}
</div>
```

courses.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Course } from '../shared/model/course';
import { CoursesService } from '../shared/model/courses.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-courses',
    templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {

    courses$: Observable<Course[]>;
    selectedCourse$: Observable<Course>;
    courseUrl: string;

    constructor( 
        private coursesService: CoursesService 
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.courses$ = this.coursesService.findAllCourses( );

        this.selectedCourse$ = this.coursesService.findCourseByUrl(this.courseUrl);
    }

    onSelect(course: Course): void {
        console.log(course);
        this.selectedCourse$ = course;
    }

    onChange(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        this.selectedCourse$ = newValue;
    }

}
```

I can select the course, but the course description will not show up in the div below. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make your select, it is no longer an Observable, but a plain JS object. The `newValue` you are using to assign the chosen value is an object, so `selectedCourse` is therefore an object.

Also, you cannot access `course` from outside the select, like you have tried to do in your conditional div. So there you should display `{{ selectedCourse$.description }}` instead of `{{ course.description }}` All in all your conditional div should look like this (I've removed the dollar sign)

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCourse">
   {{ selectedCourse.description }}
</div>
```

and your ngModel should also then be just:

```
[ngModel]="selectedCourse"
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2f8lS5JOWSgzRAB0IAj?p=preview)

Comment: You are very welcome! Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer ;) Furthermore, happy coding! :)

Comment: Splendid! I'm new here. Thanks for your kind reminder on the tick.